# App engine cookie based traffic splitting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, traffic

Is there a way to use app engine traffic splitting to present a specific version to a selected set of pilot users ?  As per the doc below , it seems it provides capability but does not provide  how to find what cookie value corresponds to what version

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/splitting-traffic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE : Got the answer from google groups and forums .Consider traffic is spilt based on cookie with version A to receive 40% and version B to receive remaining  60% . So GOOGAPUID cookie values less than 400 will route the traffic to version A , cookie values of 400-999 will route the traffic to version B

Comment: how did you set the cookies GOOGAPUID ? 
We also have the same requirement. To test the new version by set of people.

Comment: @VikramShinde you may want either write the cookie on the server side by sending the following HTTP header with a response e.g. `Set-Cookie: GOOGAPUID=100` or write the cookie from the client, for example by executing JavaScript statement `document.cookie = "GOOGAPUID=100"` in web browser.